# How to run tests conditionally in NUNIT?

Tags: testing, nunit

I'd like to be able to set a condition from which to decide whether certain tests run in NUNIT.

For example if a global variable x = 1 then only run the tests from a certain class/assembly or only run the first test.

Is anything like this possible?

How would one go about doing this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [Categories](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2) with your NUnit tests. This would allow you to run groups of them at a time, or all at once.

While [Categories](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2) seem like the "more pure" way to do this, you could programmatically skip tests like this post asks: [Programmatically skip an nunit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095504/programatically-skip-an-nunit-test). It seems to me, this approach is what you're looking for though.

Comment: How to run categories in the command line? In the wiki, it's mentioned to use /include or /exclude argument. But how to use it exactly? Any example please?