# Running same NUnit tests with different objects

Tags: nunit

Is there a way to run an identical set of tests over multiple objects, but toggle each test depending on the type of said objects?

i.e. if I had classes

```
abstract class  MyObj{  abstract bool DoWork(bool isTrue);                 }
class SubObj1 : MyObj{  override bool DoWork(bool IsTrue){return IsTrue; } }
class SubObj2 : MyObj{  override bool DoWork(bool IsTrue){return false;  } }
```

and tests

```
class Tests
{
    [Test]
    void Test1()    {   Assert.IsTrue(new SubObj1().DoWork(true))   }
    [Test]
    void Test2()    {   Assert.IsTrue(new SubObj1().DoWork(false))  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to use flags, type checking, or something so that I:

- could replace the references to `SubObj1` with a `MyObj` instance,
- <s>Run the class `Tests` over both `SubObj1` and `SubObj2`, but prevent `Test1` from running if working with a `SubObj2` instance?</s> **EDIT:** This part can be done with [`Assert.Ignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095504/programatically-skip-an-nunit-test).

(The real case in my code involves three different unstructured-data parsers, each of which trade simplicity for accuracy in a different way. I have 400 test cases for one parser, and would like to port them to the other two. Creating three nearly identical sets of tests cases and pruning the tests that don't work in each class seems like a massive DRY failure.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it very easy with [TestCaseSourceAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.1). Something like:

```
class Tests
{
    static object[] TestCases = new object[] 
       {
           new object[] { new SubObj1(), true }
           new object[] { new SubObj2(), false}
       };

    [Test, TestCaseSource("TestCases")]
    void Test1(MyObj obj, bool isTrue)    {   Assert.IsTrue(obj.DoWork(isTrue))   }
}
```

(I did not try to compile it, just shared the basic idea).

Comment: Thanks. a) Will this show up as multiple test cases in NUnit? (i.e. can I make is appear to be Test1_1, Test1_2, etc., or something like that?)

Comment: Test names do appear differently. You'll see something like: Namespace.TestClassName.Test_Method_Here("and TestCase string here")

Comment: This is actually depends on the unit test runner. I remember that R# will show them as separate tests, but I do not remember how default VS unit test runner shows them.