# Selective Ignore of NUnit tests

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to ignore certain tests based on data I pulled from a configuration file during the `TestFixtureSetUp`. Is there a way to ignore running a test based on parameters?

```
[TestFixture]
public class MessagesTests
{
    private bool isPaidAccount;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Init () {
        isPaidAccount = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsPaidAccount"] == "True";
    }

    [Test]
    //this test should run only if `isPaidAccount` is true
    public void Message_Without_Template_Is_Sent()
    {
         //this tests an actual web api call.
    }

}
```

If account we are testing with is a paid account, the test should run fine, if not, the method will throw an exception.

Would there be an extension of the attribute `[Ignore(ReallyIgnore = isPaidAccount )]`? Or should I write this inside the method and run 2 separate test cases for eg.

```
    public void Message_Without_Template_Is_Sent()
    {
         if(isPaidAccount)
         {
              //test for return value here
         }
         else
         {
              //test for exception here
         }
    }
```

Comment: `Assert.Ignore()` within the test.

Comment: @Matthew so its good practice to just check the condition before and ignore the test?

Comment: make it an answer pls

Comment: @ShawnMclean It sounds like those are two separate tests. You should test *both* cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Assert.Ignore()` like Matthew states. You could also use `Assert.Inconclusive()` if you want to categorize the result differently.

This Question/Answer is slightly similar: [Programmatically skip an nunit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095504/programatically-skip-an-nunit-test)