# How to skip a Unit Test at runtime?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, featuretoggle

Thanks in advance!

We have some Automation tests using the selenium web driver which are great and provide a really good regression pack.

The problem is now we have feature toggles in our code. So I need to say ignore these tests unless that feature toggle is turned On/ Off. I can't find anything really searching Google.

Ideally I don't want a 'if' statement at the top of the Feature tests but it looks like it's going to be the main way. My initial thoughts where to create a custom attribute

```
public class IsFeatureFlagTurnedOn : Attribute
{
   public IsFeatureFlagTurnedOn(string featureToggleName)
   {
      FeatureToggleName = featureToggleName;
   }
   public string FeatureToggleName {get;}
}

public class MyTests 
{
   [TestMethod]
   [IsFeatureFlagTurnedOn("MyFeature1")]
   public void ItShould()
   {
      // only run if MyFeature1 is turned on
   }
}
```

I some how need to hook into the MSTest pipeline and say if this attribute is present and the logic for MyFeature1 is turned off then don't run this test -  Looked at dynamically adding the [Ignore] but with no luck.

This is running through VSTS and I could use [TestCategories] but I'd have to keep updating the pipeline to which feature is turned on/off which I don't want to do.

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSTest v2 now has a lot of extensibility points, and you can achieve this by extending the `TestMethodAttribute`. First we add two attribute arguments, a `string` for a property name and a `Type` that has the property. Then we override the `Execute` method and invoke the property via reflection. If the result is `true`, we'll execute the test as normal, otherwise we return an 'inconclusive` test result.

```
public class TestMethodWithConditionAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
{
    public Type ConditionParentType { get; set; }
    public string ConditionPropertyName { get; set; }

    public TestMethodWithConditionAttribute(string conditionPropertyName, Type conditionParentType)
    {
        ConditionPropertyName = conditionPropertyName;
        ConditionParentType = conditionParentType;
    }

    public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
    {
        if (ConditionParentType.GetProperty(ConditionPropertyName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)?.GetValue(null) is bool condiiton && condiiton)
        {
            return base.Execute(testMethod);
        }
        else
        {
            return new TestResult[] { new TestResult {  Outcome = UnitTestOutcome.Inconclusive } };
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can use our new attribute like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{
    [TestMethodWithCondition(nameof(Configuration.IsMyFeature1Enabled), typeof(Configuration))]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public static class Configuration
{
    public static bool IsMyFeature1Enabled => false;
}
```

---

The above is a very generic solution. You could also customize it a little more to your particular use case to perhaps avoid quite so much verbosity in the attribute declaration:

```
public class TestMethodForConfigAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TestMethodForConfigAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
    {
        if (IsConfigEnabled(Name))
        {
            return base.Execute(testMethod);
        }
        else
        {
            return new TestResult[] { new TestResult {  Outcome = UnitTestOutcome.Inconclusive } };
        }
    }

    public static bool IsConfigEnabled(string name)
    {
        //...
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{
    [TestMethodForConfig("MyFeature1")]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! #H5YR

Answer (score 1):

Based on my reading of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095504/programmatically-skip-an-nunit-test), you may need to use [`Assert.Inconclusive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms244275%28v%3dvs.90%29)